# Exporting Python Dataframe to sql server hosted on local network

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, urllib

I am trying to output a dataframe to SQL through PYTHON to  SQL server hosted on a different machine within our network and am using the following code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

param_str = "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER" + server + ";DATABASE" + ";UID" + username + ";PWD=" + password
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(param_str)
print(params)
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
print(engine)

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age']) 
df.to_sql('test', con=engine, if_exists='replace')
```

However, this is producing an interface error with the following text

> (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>   (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at:
>   http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

Comment: **UPDATE**: I have added the equal signs on some of the parameters and it still produces the same error

Comment: I'm not sure but is pyodbc installed and configured on your machine ? You also don't seem to provide a database to the params

Comment: Also, check if that driver is installed on client machine: `print(pyodbc.drivers())`. Do note: [SQL Server Native Client is deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15). Use [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) (likely not in sqlalchemy docs).